# Z index is not working for a drop down component which is placed in side a disclosure panel.

Tags: css, user-interface, gwt, z-index, dropdown

I have a custom GWT drop down component which is a combination of a text box,vertical panel which contains check boxes.

I have to placed this component inside GWT disclosure panel.When the panel is expanded and when the user clicks on the component the drop down must appear on the top of the main page content instead of expanding the disclosure panel or going below the main page.

I have tried with z index with higher values still the drop down is going inside  the disclosure panel.

Is there any other CSS tricks which can help me to solve this issue.

Comment: It might help if you post how its being rendered in the browser along with the effective css. [Minimum, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Jon thanks for your response. Right now I'm not able to upload an Image of the browser.I have added Z-index property to the vertical panel which will expand when you click on the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position : relative;` to the dropdown wrapper along with `z-index`. You might have to test different values of `z-index`'s for it to work depending on your code.

Comment: I have changed the position  from relative to static. No the widget is working perfectly.